# Partial text search in mongoDB for url type using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my collections, I have an URL field like below.

```
{
  _id   : "5cff700417bb15283c7bd011"
  url   : "/xyz/hai-detail.aspx?productid=em630"
}
```

I wanted to implement a partial text search for the url field using mongoose. I am using regex for the partial text as shown below.

```
const Url = require('../models/url');     
const query = {}
  if (url) {
    query.url = new RegExp(url, 'gi')
  }

Url.find(query)
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        user: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error:", err);
      res.status(500).json({
        "error": err
      });
    });
```

But I was getting empty array when I search with some portion of the URL.

```
http://localhost:3000/urls/all?url=/xyz/hai-detail.a
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `Collection.findOne({ "url" : { $regex: /urls/, $options: 'i' } })`

Comment: @metha-rohan, I tried it, but it was not working.

Comment: This worked for me..!

query.url= new RegExp(encodeURI(url).replace('?', '\\?'), 'gi')